# Traveling to USA with tripod attached to my camera bag

Tags: air-travel, gear, luggage, photography

I like to travel with my DSLR and I have nice slingshot bag for it which I can take with me on the plane along with my carry on. This [picture](http://img2.fengniao.com/product/33/94/ceb0ZMiwEAVl2.jpg) shows what I want to do while boarding the plane. Would it be OK/legal for me while flying from Canada to USA?

Comment: somewhat related question over on Photo.SE: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13440/1872

Comment: that question is similar but what I am asking is if I have a pouch with my tripod and have it attached to my camera bag and not have problems traveling. I know it should be fine when I put it inside my carry on luggage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just flew within the US last week with a TriPod without issue.  Mine was a little smaller, and didn't clip on to anything else, but TSA and the airline didn't give me any issues.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have an issue, I've flown with my Manfrotto + ball head (the one with the leg warmers) all over the world, including the US and it was never a problem. The only time you should really consider a tripod is when entering a train station, or other places where photography is restricted without a permit of some kind. In those cases, pack a monopod :)

Comment: Was this a bulky full-size tripod or their slim model?

Comment: @rlesko It was the full sized model.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have a problem, from my experience most airlines allow two carry-on articles.  As long as the requirements are met, you should be fine.  Here is an example for [Air Canada's Rules](http://www.aircanada.com/en/travelinfo/airport/baggage/carry-on.html)

Answer (score 3):

You should be fine, however unless you're not planning to check luggage you may want to consider tossing it into your checked bag.

My manfrotto tripod is 25.79 in when closed, without the head so it's just easier for me to pack it in a bag.  If you do decide to carry-on make sure you're comfortable moving in a crowd with the bag and tripod.  Make sure it will still fit in an overhead bin. And, be ready for security to be worried that you're carrying a large club, just in case.