# Taking a tripod on an Aeroflot, Kingfisher or Air India flight?

Tags: luggage, photography, aeroflot, kingfisher-airlines, air-india

May I carry a tripod as carry-on luggage or do I have to check it in when on an international flight?
Having it strapped to my backpack is fine during my trip but I'm worried it might get stuck somewhere at the airport while on conveyor belts.

I would like to know the answer to this question in general but am mostly interested in policies by Aeroflot, Kingfisher Airlines and Air India.

Comment: Also see [Traveling to USA with tripod attached to my camera bag](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/545/108) and [How can I protect camera equipment in checked baggage?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/232/108)

Comment: OK... Please don't close the question just yet as I'd like to see whether anyone can provide answers for aforementioned airlines. I did try to call Aeroflot Croatia but no one was answering for about an hour.

Comment: BTW, I don't know why I don't see relevant recommended questions related to mine while writing. I noticed that for my last three questions.

Comment: No idea what the algorithm used is. Probably has been answered on Meta.StackOverflow.

Comment: Certainly not Kingfisher, but not due to its policies. http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/Kingfisher-Airlines-crisis-More-flights-cancelled-pilots-resign/articleshow/11973509.cms

Comment: It's definitely gonna be an interesting India trip since I have a couple of flights with them booked already.

Comment: I'll report back once I get on the flights. Thanks for the bounty thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe one can carry tripods on carry-on bags. But its advisable to fit that inside the luggage than strapped to backpack/camera bag. I've carried my tripod like this on two occasions.

First time I traveled on Jet Airways - a domestic flight between Bangalore and Delhi. I packed that in a kit (one similar to sports bag) and a friend who was travelling with me packed his tripod in his rucksack. We were allowed to to carry them.

Second time was on an international flight - Emirates (from London to Bangalore via Dubai). This time the tripod was in a hard case carry on bag. And there was no problem carrying it.

Jet Airways, Kingfisher and Air India being Indian airline operators - they have almost similar guidelines. So carrying a tripod on these might not be an issue.

EDIT by OP:

- Aeroflot allows tripods on their planes but I wasn't able to bring it not because of their rules but because of security check in Zagreb airport.
- Kingfisher Airlines does NOT allow tripods on any of their flights nor does Go Air.
- Air India allows tripods on all their flights except the ones to and from Leh, Jammu and Srinagar.

Comment: I made a bag for it from ripstop nylon and will ask at Aeroflot's airport office just before the flight whether I have to check it in or not. Luckily it attaches to my main backpack so won't have that big of a problem in case I can't take it as carry on baggage.

Comment: Added my newly acquired info to Prashanth's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If it can fit inside a backpack it's definitely no problem.

I've never had an issue with mine (strapped to the outside of my pack) on international flights. I've never flown on Aeroflot, Kingfisher Airlines or Air India before though.