# Carrying Tripod/Monopod through security at Logan airport (Boston MA)

Tags: airport-security, photography, tsa, bos

My next trip starts at Logan airport in Boston MA.  In the experience of many locals, Logan has been more paranoid than many US airports.  While camera monopods and tripods are ok to fly with according to the TSA, I want to know if people have encountered problems at Logan airport specifically.

According to the TSA web site, tripods and monopods count as photographic equipment and can be taken on planes (size won't be an issue for mine).  In practice, these rules can be subject to local interpretation, so I'm keen to know if anyone has encountered problems with carrying on this kind of gear at Logan.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24381/tripod-in-carry-on-luggage

Comment: http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/travel-photography/1390395-tripod-carry.html this thread suggests all OK in the USA.

Comment: I got stopped both ways flying in Canada last week with the tripod in my backpack. They opened it up, saw the tripod, and let me go. Took an extra 10 minutes, that's all.

Comment: I specified Boston's Logan airport specifically for two reasons.  First, they have a history of being a bit more paranoid than other US airports.  Second, that's where my next trip starts.

Comment: Try to make it obvious that you are holding a tripod.  [Someone has mistaken it as a machine gun before](http://petapixel.com/2015/11/19/911-called-after-photographers-tripod-mistaken-for-machine-gun/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have flown through Boston Logan many, many times, as I have family in Boston.  I have carried tripod in its own case with me on multiple occasions - and never had any problems.  This has been the case with both - my old cheap £15 tripod and my current rather expensive Manfrotto one.

Once or twice I was asked to open the case so that they could inspect it in details - after which they wished my a safe trip and let me go.

Comment: The perspective of someone who has done this is exactly what I was looking for.