# Can I take a tripod on board in my hand luggage?

Tags: hand-luggage, photography

I would like to know if a camera tripod (let's say not the biggest one, 40-50 cm folded) can be taken on board inside hand luggage, or it has to be put into the aircraft hold?

Is there any problem for camera (DSLR) and lenses as well?

Comment: This depends on the airline. So we need a little more information or you could just contact the airline. They often have twitter accounts as well.

Comment: I would suggest not to check  DSL/Lens as they can easily disappear in transit.  In general never check anything you want to see again.  The only exceptions are if you have known full insurance overage and you also do not have an immediate need for the camera at your destination (or you are traveling domestically in USA and can co-pack with a declared weapon).  But it's fine to put cameras in hand luggage.

Comment: outbound flight is with ryanair and return is with vueling, destination is portugal and spain. The real question is, I think, if, in case of problems, i can check the tripod once at the gate. thank you

Comment: i do not own any insurance and, infact, i'd like to take camera, lens and tripod with me. I have read somewhere in the internet that if the secutiry agent stops the tripod, then i can check it and put it into the aircraft hold. What do you suggest?

Comment: Tri-pods aren't bigger than many musical instruments I have seen on flights.  I'd say hand carry it and deal with the consequences.  But it would be better all around if it was packed in some sort of travel case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tripod in Carry-on Luggage](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24381/tripod-in-carry-on-luggage)

Answer (score 2):

If it is within the airline's dimension for a carry-on, then yes.

Note however, they might legitimately count it as one carry-on toward your allowance.

Also, whoever is staffing the terminal entrance may do an extra check.

Any camera should be no problem.  I would never check a camera.

Comment: ok, so if it fits inside my backpack, or whatever my carry-on luggage is going to be, and it satisfies the airline's dimension, that will be fine, right?

Comment: Yes, if it fits, it fits.  Just make sure you can easily remove and repack it i case you get hassled about it at the terminal entrance.