# Tripod in Carry-on Luggage in Europe

Tags: hand-luggage, eu, tripod

I'm going to Europe next year but I'm unsure if I can carry a tripod in my carry-on luggage. I saw a couple of question here to cite some:

- [Tripod in Carry-on Luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24381/tripod-in-carry-on-luggage)
- [Compact tripod on airplane (Europe)](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/90751/compact-tripod-on-airplane-europe)
- [How can I best take a tripod on a plane trip!](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60180/how-can-i-best-take-a-tripod-on-a-plane-trip)

All those questions may be outdated due the laws changing. I'd like to know if, within the Europe Union, is there some general regulations that, allows or not, tripod in carry-on luggage. If you can provide any official link attesting this information, it would be essential.

I'll travel within France, Netherlands and Portugal territory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually travel with a tripod in my backpack or carry-on suitcase, and never had an issue. Nobody ever asked anything about it. Lowcost or traditional airlines didn't make a difference.

FYI: this is my tripod: [Neewer](https://www.amazon.it/Neewer-10089287-Treppiedi-Alluminio-Fotocamera/dp/B01MSAEZN8)

I have also a slightly bigger one which didn't raise a question either.

An official answer about it has been given by airfrance on facebook: 
[here](https://www.facebook.com/airfrance/posts/hi-i-can-carry-the-tripod-in-hand-luggage/10154065806310526/)

> Hello Valeria, thank you for contacting us on Facebook today. You can carry a tripod in your handluggage as long as the dimensions and weight are respected. Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

What is said in the other questions still applies: There is no specific regulations on tripods, and they don't see to fall into any category of [prohibited items](https://www.lufthansa.com/content/dam/lh/documents/prepare-for-your-trip/baggage/dangerous-goods/gefaehrliche-und-verbotene-gueter.pdf). There may be a chance that it could be considered a "blunt instrument", but the category seems to be for weapon-type things like baseball bats. So it should be fine in most cases, but nobody here can give you a guarantee.

Also most low cost carriers here can be pretty strict about the "1 bag" per person and other carry-on rules. They may ask you to fit the thing *inside* your bag, and refuse to take it if it is larger than the allowed dimensions for hand luggage.

In the end it will also come down to the type of tripod. I regularly take a cheap, tiny thing that easily fits into my backpack. It never raises an eyebrow. However, if you'd show up with a large and heavy wooden contraption they might ask.